# Null error when attempting to set back button using custom toolbar and navigation components

Tags: android, kotlin, toolbar, android-toolbar, android-architecture-navigation

It's my first time using Navigation components and I'm struggling a bit to set it up with my custom toolbar. I can navigate between views fine but now I'd like to show a back button on the inner views. However, I keep getting `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference` error and not sure what I'm doing wrong please.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
  
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

    val navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController) // NPE happening here
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment))

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHolder"
        layout="@layout/snippet_toolbar_plain" />

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

snippet_toolbar_plain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/yellow"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvToolbarTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Tracker" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbarHolder"
    layout="@layout/snippet_toolbar_plain" />
```

The `android:id` you put here replaces the ID on the root element of your `layout/snippet_toolbar_plain` element. Therefore `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` is returning `null` - you have no view named `toolbar` anymore, only the element now named `toolbarHolder`. This means you don't have an ActionBar set at all (you've set it to null), which is why `getSupportActionBar()` is returning null and you're getting a `NullPointerException`.

You can simply remove the `android:id="@+id/toolbarHolder"` and your `findViewById(R.id.toolbar)` will return a non-null Toolbar. Or you can change your `findViewById` to use `R.id.toolbarHolder`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing findViewById to use R.id.toolbarHolder didn't really work for me but removing the id from the included layout did the trick and now I have ```<include
            layout="@layout/snippet_toolbar_plain" />```. Cheers.